# How do you return true if sub-list at index i, if any, is in ascending order

Tags: java, arraylist, sub-array

How do you return  true if sub-list at index i, if any, is in ascending order (each item is less than or equal to the next item); and false otherwise. This is what I have done so far. However, I can't seem to get the test to pass

```
public static boolean isAscending(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list, int i) {

    ArrayList<Integer> data = list.get(i);
    for (i = 0; i < data.size() - 1; i++) {
        if (data.get(i) > data.get(i + 1)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

@Test @Graded(description="IsAscendingBasic")
public void testIsAscendingBasic() {
    assertFalse(ListOfListService.isAscending(emptyList, 0));

    assertFalse(ListOfListService.isAscending(oneRow, 0));
    assertFalse(ListOfListService.isAscending(oneRow, 1));
    assertFalse(ListOfListService.isAscending(oneRow, -1));

    assertTrue(ListOfListService.isAscending(list2, 0));
    assertFalse(ListOfListService.isAscending(list2, 1));
    assertFalse(ListOfListService.isAscending(list2, 2));
    assertTrue(ListOfListService.isAscending(list2, 3));
    assertTrue(ListOfListService.isAscending(list2, 4));
    assertTrue(ListOfListService.isAscending(list2, 5));

    list2.get(4).set(1, 20); // 20, 20
    assertTrue(ListOfListService.isAscending(list2, 4));

    assertTrue(ListOfListService.isAscending(list1, 1));

    assertTrue(ListOfListService.isAscending(list3_emptySubLists, 0)); // empty sub-list is ascending
    assertFalse(ListOfListService.isAscending(list3_emptySubLists, 1));
    currentMethodName = new Throwable().getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName();
}

@Test @Graded(description="IsAscendingComprehensive")
public void testIsAscendingComprehensive() {
    testIsAscendingBasic();
    assertFalse(ListOfListService.isAscending(null, 0));

    assertFalse(ListOfListService.isAscending(list4_nullItems, 0));
    assertTrue(ListOfListService.isAscending(list4_nullItems, 2));
    assertFalse(ListOfListService.isAscending(list4_nullItems, 3));
    assertFalse(ListOfListService.isAscending(list4_nullItems, 5));
    currentMethodName = new Throwable().getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName();
}
```

Comment: in `isAscending` you have `i` as parameter, so why do you make for-each loop? `i` is overriden.

Comment: What test fails?